# dd() returning null when I try to find data by user id

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

I am trying to retrieve data from the database by user_id. My view shows this error : Trying to get property of non-object. dd() return null.

This is my Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Complain;
use App\Feedback;
use App\Item;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Session;
use Auth;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function profile($id){

      $complain = Complain::find($id);
      dd($complain);
      return view('user.profile')->with(['complains' => User::find($id)->complains]);

    }
}
```

This is my User Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surname', 'regnumber', 'course', 'department', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function complains()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Complain');
    }
}
```

This is my Complain Model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Complain extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'user_id', 'title', 'body', 'name', 'regnumber'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

This is my view :

```
@foreach($complains as $complain)
   <div>
    <h3 class="operator-complain-title">Title: </h3>
    <p>{{ $complain->title }}</p>
    <h3 class="operator-complain-title">Complain:</h3>
    <p>{{ $complain->body }}</p>
   </div>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

The user_id is a foreign key. How do I successfully show complains(data) based on the user_id?

This is my users table:

```
id | name | email | password
7    John   email   password
```

This is my complains table :

```
id | user_id | title     | body
5      7      complain 1   Complain 1
```

Anyone with ideas please share.

Comment: $complains = Complain::where('user_id', $id)->get();

Answer (score 2):

As I understand You want to get complains by user `$id`.

So doing `Complain::find($id)` will not return user's complain, cuz find gets by `id` field.

But You want to get complains by `user_id` field.

So for that case: `Complain::whereUserId($id)->get()`

Check this one (recommended when You're going to show user's data and it's complains):

```
public function profile(Request $request, $id){
  $User = User::with(['complains'])->find($id);
  if(!$User) return abort(404, 'User with id:'.$id.' not found');

  return view('user.profile')->with(['user' => $User, 'complains' => $User->complains]);
}
```

or this one (if You're going to show complains only):

```
public function profile(Request $request, $id){
  $complains = Complain::whereUserId($id)->get();
  if(!$complains) return abort(404, 'No complains for user (id:'.$id.') found');

  return view('user.profile')->with(['complains' => $complains]);
}
```

In case of `$id` is name of user:

```
public function profile(Request $request, $name){
  $User = User::with(['complains'])->whereName($name)->first();
  if(!$User) return abort(404, 'User with name:'.$name.' not found');

  return view('user.profile')->with(['user' => $User, 'complains' => $User->complains]);
}
```

Comment: The first solution returns this : Trying to get property of non-object. pointing to this :  return view('user.profile')->with(['complains' => $User->complains]); The second solution returns my view but does not output the complain from the table complains.

Comment: seems like You don't pass `7` as user's id?

Comment: Your updated answers work but only when I manually type in the id number like this :$complains = Complain::whereUserId(7)->get(); How do I dynamically obtain the ID?

Comment: ok, @Martin try to change action arguments as in my updated answer

Comment: I have changed the action arguments, view does not output the complains..

Comment: hmmm try to `dd($id);` right under action, what it will show?

Comment: He does to check `$id`

Comment: by url. let's say `domain.com/profile/7` so he need query the segment. or `$id = Auth::user()->id`

Comment: dd($id) returns "John" which is the name of the user with user_id 7

Comment: @Martin (:   what?   hahaha sec, I'll do it for Your requirement (:

Comment: @Martin check my updated answer. But keep in mind there may be tons of users with name `John`, try to change link that show's profile by id to pass `/profile/7` not `/profile/John`

Comment: @Martin John? then need to have `whereName()`

Comment: How can I redirect users to their profile after login? I have this in my login controller : protected $redirectTo = '/home'; What url should I use?

Comment: @Martin actually it depends how You've done it. Usually: `Auth::user()->id` returns id of user in session. But I would recommend You to use profile action without id: `public function profile(Request $request) {` and inside of it do: `$id = Auth::id();`

Comment: This does not return output based on user_id. For example when the url is profile/7 or profile/9 the view shows output for user with user_id 7.

Comment: If this is for user itself, change the `$User = User::with(['complains'])->find($id);` to `$User = User::with(['complains'])->find(Auth::user()->id);` then just use /profile. To redirect change the path `protected $redirectTo = '/profile';`

Answer (score 0):

You would try to check first if the object is null or empty before trying to consume it like

```
<?php
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
    echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function profile($id)
```

should be

```
public function profile(Request $request)
```

And on Eloquent

```
$complain = Complain::find($request->id);
```

Or get query from segment. Example domain/id/ = id from slug number 1

```
$complain = Complain::find($request->segment(1));
```

Comment: seems like You've not dive in issue to understand why example did not work in question. See Marting tries to get complains by providing `$id` that represents user's id. If You're familiar with Eloquent You must understand that `find` gets by primary key, not by related field.

Comment: @num8er from the controller. `dd($complain);` before view. For this case `$id` is null. So operator need to know the $id value

Comment: He does not check `$id`, he checks `$complain` so `$id = 7` and of course `$complain == null`

Comment: I change my function as above and return my view as : return view('user.profile')->withComplain($complain); but I get this error : Undefined variable: complains on my view..

Comment: @Martin please check my answer and examples defined there and comment under of it what happened.